# matplotlib data stack on Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i get this code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price in $')
df['Close'].plot(ax=ax1, color='r', lw=2.)
signals[['short_mavg', 'long_mavg']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2.)

ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == 1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == 1.0],
         '^', markersize=10, color='m')
         
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == -1.0],
         'v', markersize=10, color='k')
         
plt.show()
```

the problem is : all of the '^' and 'v' and 'Date" values from df, placed on Y axis =(

Ill added all code part of my jupyter notebook and .csv sample
csv data:

```
2013.12.17,00:00,0.89469,0.89571,0.88817,0.88973,4
2013.12.18,00:00,0.88974,0.89430,0.88200,0.88595,4
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv("AUDUSD.csv",header = None)
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'] 
df=df.set_index('Date')
```

second df:

```
short_window = 20
long_window = 90
signals = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index) 
signals['signal'] = 0.0 
#calculating MAs
signals['short_mavg'] = df['Close'].rolling(short_window).mean()
signals['long_mavg'] = df['Close'].rolling(long_window).mean() 

signals['signal'][short_window:] = np.where(signals['short_mavg'][short_window:] 
                                            > signals['long_mavg'][short_window:], 1.0, 0.0) 
signals['positions'] = signals['signal'].diff()
```

Comment: please supply a working example, what is `df`

Comment: It's difficulty to understand what you mean. Can you add a working example?

Comment: added all other parts of code,

Comment: I got the AUDUSD rate from yfinance and created a graph with your code, but it did not gather on the y-axis and could be drawn correctly. Would you mind posting the current graph and sample data?

Comment: my sample data: https://dropmefiles.com/NlFjg

Comment: my screen: https://dropmefiles.com/a4s6u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a graph with your code using Yahoo Finance currency data. It may be that the time series data is not indexed. Please check your data and my data content.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker("AUDUSD=X")
df = ticker.history(start='2013-01-01', end='2021-01-01')
short_window = 20
long_window = 90
signals = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index) 
signals['signal'] = 0.0 
#calculating MAs
signals['short_mavg'] = df['Close'].rolling(short_window).mean()
signals['long_mavg'] = df['Close'].rolling(long_window).mean() 

signals['signal'][short_window:] = np.where(signals['short_mavg'][short_window:] 
                                            > signals['long_mavg'][short_window:], 1.0, 0.0) 
signals['positions'] = signals['signal'].diff()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price in $')
df['Close'].plot(ax=ax1, color='r', lw=2.)
signals[['short_mavg', 'long_mavg']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2.)

ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == 1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == 1.0],
         '^', markersize=10, color='m')
         
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == -1.0],
         'v', markersize=10, color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
signals

    signal  short_mavg  long_mavg   positions
Date                
2012-12-31  0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
2013-01-01  0.0     NaN     NaN     0.0
2013-01-02  0.0     NaN     NaN     0.0
2013-01-03  0.0     NaN     NaN     0.0
2013-01-04  0.0     NaN     NaN     0.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2020-12-25  1.0     0.749732    0.727486    0.0
2020-12-28  1.0     0.750791    0.727987    0.0
2020-12-29  1.0     0.751951    0.728454    0.0
2020-12-30  1.0     0.753096    0.728910    0.0
2020-12-31  1.0     0.754453    0.729403    0.0
```

Comment: fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))    #there are was missing "f" in this string.. and with this fix its working as it should

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected it.

Comment: ill get, what was the problem in my code. i was using wrong datetime format in csv files, but adding this string convert it to normal one "df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)"